# Which Greek myth tells the story of a woman/man who falsely admits to killing his/her lover?

Tags: greek

Someone told me about a Greek myth about a woman/man who falsely admits to killing his/her lover? Is there such a myth? If so, what is it?

Comment: Where have you searched yourself? This avoids us going over the same sources

Comment: I recently read a book called Mythos. It mentions that cupid liked a girl and made her his bride. But her jealous sisters made her suspect him (a little more complex than this) and then he leaves her. So then she goes to her sisters and tells them that he would rather be with them than her, ultimately killing them (individually)..  cant recall about killing the lover in the story.